# How to fit a straight line to part of a curve

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I have a set of data from a `pd.DataFrame` which looks like this, with a 3rd-order polynomial fitted to it:

[image]
which is fit by

```
# Find the 3rd-order polynomial which fits the SED
coefs = poly.polyfit(x, y, 3) # find the coeffs
x_new = np.linspace(lower, upper, num=len(x)*10) # space to plot the fit
ffit = poly.Polynomial(coefs) # find the polynomial
```

How could I find the straight line that fits only part of the data, for example, just the downward slope within 9.5 < x < 15 ?

I could slice the dataframe into pieces with

```
left = pks[pks[xvar] < nu_to]
right = pks[pks[xvar] > nu_to]
```

but I'd like to avoid that, since I'll have to do the same thing with many datasets.

[This question is about MatLab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763444/fit-a-line-to-a-part-of-a-plot)
This current question is a distillation of [my previous one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74147461/finding-two-linear-fits-on-different-domains-in-the-same-data)

Comment: The answer depends on the amount of high frequency variations in your dataset. My first suggestion would be to put 0 in  second and third coefficients. Can you plot the results?

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. My confusion lies not in what the coefficients should be, but in how to restrict the straight line to a range of x values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding two linear fits on different domains in the same data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74147461/finding-two-linear-fits-on-different-domains-in-the-same-data)

Comment: No, because that's also my question. I'll edit this one to make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the curve shape is always going to be similar to the example, you could fit a line to the portion of your dataset limited by the ymax and ymin values. You could automate the detection of that subset by calculating the y range between the ymax and ymin values, as well as the corresponding x values. The use of the min and max inside the slice is to take into account the min and max values of y might not always be in the same order:

```
linearx = x[min(np.argmax(y), np.argmin(y)): max(np.argmax(y), np.argmin(y))+1]
lineary = y[min(np.argmax(y), np.argmin(y)): max(np.argmax(y), np.argmin(y))+1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just use the linear part of your polynomial fit.
The idea is to get slope and offset by first eliminating the quadratic term.
Say you have

`y = a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d`,

setting `x -> x - b / 3a` removes the quadratic term. The remaining function has a linear slope of

`c' = c - b^2 / 3a`

and an offset of

`d'= d-b c / 3a + 2b^3 / 27a^2`.

Transforming the linear part back gives you the final offset

`d'' = d - b^3/ 27a^2`

so the linear part is given by

`y = ( c - b^2 / 3a ) x + d - b^3/ 27a^2`